# Eigenvalue of Orbital Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum

I read a literature, which discusses the orbital operator.

$^2$ and $_$ are square of the orbital operator and the $z$-axis component of orbital operator respectively. $|l\rangle$ and $|m\rangle$ are the eigenvectors for the $^2$ and $_$ operators respectively. $_+$ is defined as $_+=_+_$.

The literature says that $$(^2+2ℏ−2ℏ_+)|\rangle=(^2+3)ℏ^2|\rangle \tag{1}$$ and $$_|\rangle=ℏ|\rangle \tag{2}$$

I do not understand why it is like that. I can understand that $^2|\rangle=(+1)ℏ^2|\rangle$
because $|l\rangle$ is the eigenvector of the square of the orbital operator ($L^2$). If $|l\rangle$ is replaced by $|m\rangle$, I can understand that $_|\rangle=ℏ|\rangle$.

However, $|l\rangle$ is not the eigenvector of the $z$-axis component of orbital operator ($_$). How does the author obtain that $(2ℏ_−2ℏ_+)|\rangle=2ℏ^2|\rangle$ and $_|\rangle=(+1)ℏ|\rangle$

Could anyone give me some hint on these equations (1) and (2)? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you sure about $(2)$? That should be $L_z|l,l\rangle=l\hbar|l,l\rangle$.

Comment: "The literature says that" -- which literature? Your second equation is definitely wrong, but it's hard to tell if your source is wrong, or whether you've misinterpreted it, without a precise reference.

Answer (score 3):

$L^2$ and $L_z$ commute, so it's possible to find a simultaneous eigenbasis of both operators.  We label the states in this basis $|l,m\rangle$, where
$$L^2|l,m\rangle = l(l+1)\hbar^2|l,m\rangle$$
$$L_z|l,m\rangle = m\hbar^2|l,m\rangle$$

The state $|l,l\rangle$ is such an eigenstate with $m=l$, so
$$L_z|l,l\rangle=l\hbar|l,l\rangle$$ and
$$L^2|l,l\rangle=l(l+1)\hbar^2|l,l\rangle$$

Note also that $L_+|l,l\rangle=0$.

Comment: @JMurray@EmilioPisanty Thank you very much for your comments and suggestions. I wrote equation 2 in the wrong way. It should be $L_z|ll\rangle=l\hbar |ll\rangle$. I have already modified my post. On the other hand, the second $l$ in the simultaneous eigenbasis $|ll\rangle$ is still the eigen vector $m$ for the orbital operator $L$. This $m$ just takes the maximum state and becomes $l$ when the first $l$ takes the state $l$. This is why the $m$ is written as $l$ in the second simultaneous eigenbasis $|ll\rangle$. Is my understanding correct? Thank you again.